# Logic to insert 0 for multiple columns in first row - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df that may contain `nan` values for two columns in the first row. If true I want to replace these values with `0`. However, if there are integers there then leave as is. So this df should replace `X,Y` with `0`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({   
    'Code1' : ['A','A','B','B','C','C'],    
    'Code2' : [np.nan,np.nan,5,np.nan,np.nan,10],                      
    'X' : [np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,3],    
    'Y' : [np.nan,np.nan,2,np.nan,np.nan,4],                                   
    })
```

1)

```
if df.loc[0,'X':'Y'] == np.nan:
    df.loc[:0, 'X':'Y'] = 0
```

2)

```
if df.loc[[0],['X','Y']].isnull():
    df.loc[:0, 'X':'Y'] = 0
else:
     pass
```

But this example df should not replace with 0 as integers exist:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({   
    'Code1' : ['A','A','B','B','C','C'],    
    'Code2' : [np.nan,np.nan,5,np.nan,np.nan,10],                      
    'X' : [5,np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,3],    
    'Y' : [6,np.nan,2,np.nan,np.nan,4],                                   
    })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df.loc[0, ['X', 'Y']] = df.loc[0, ['X', 'Y']].fillna(0)
>>>> df
  Code1  Code2    X    Y
0     A    NaN  0.0  0.0
1     A    NaN  NaN  NaN
2     B    5.0  1.0  2.0
3     B    NaN  NaN  NaN
4     C    NaN  NaN  NaN
5     C   10.0  3.0  4.0
```

Comment: But I first have to determine if the first row is null. Then insert 0. If row is not null I don't want to change it.

Comment: @jonboy, `fillna` will _fill_ if and only if the target is missing. If it has some value, `fillna` has no effect.

Comment: Apologies. I was overthinking this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 if sum(pd.isnull(df.loc[0,'X':'Y']))==2:
     df.loc[0, ['X', 'Y']] = df.loc[0, ['X', 'Y']].fillna(0)
```

Comment: Thanks @Rajith. Could you explain this a little more?

Comment: `pd.isnull(df.loc[0,'X':'Y'])` checks for first row of X and Y columns are np.nan values..so it is returns a boolean array..and get sum to check count of True values.If count of True values is two,we can confirm both columns are np.nan,then you can fill with zero